# Combo Box depends on another combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with two combo boxes, one Wards the other room number.  Wards are medical units, while the rooms are room numbers (like GMU-01).

I'm trying to limit the room names based on the wards value, ie list all the bed numbers for a particular unit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TblWards].[Wards] FROM TblWards ORDER BY [TblWards].[Wards];
```

The row source from the Wards combo box (First box)

```
Private Sub Wards_AfterUpdate()
Dim txt As String
txt = "SELECT TblWards.Room FROM TblWards WHERE (TblWards.Wards)= '" & 
Me.Wards.Column(0) & "' ORDER BY TblWards.Room;"
Me.RoomN.RowSource = txt
End Sub

SELECT [TblWards].[Room] FROM TblWards WHERE ((([TblWards].[Wards])=AMU));
```

The row source from the second combo box RoomN

I get an error when I attempt to choose a value from the Wards combo box. If I line out the afterupdate code, I can choose a value.  The error is unexpected error, access needs to shut down.

Then, I get an error if I attempt to select a value from the second combobox.  asking for the AMU parameter.

I inherited this code and trying to determine how to go about it, rewrite or try to salvage it.

Comment: What error does it give? To fix the select, put quotes around the AMU, like so: `'AMU'`

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from your message, you can try this:

Private Sub cboWard_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSQL As String

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblRooms WHERE rWardID = " & Me.cboWard

Me.cboRoom.RowSource = strSQL
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry about the question.... I'm not sure why the code using txt?  from what I read on this, afterupdate was suppose to be a requery.

Comment: after update should just set the rowsource for cboRoom.  txt is just a variable for the SQL string to by placed in

Answer (score 0):

Try Following-

1. Clear ControlSource and RowSorce Property of comboBox 'RoomN' Manually.
2. Try following code in AfterEvent of 'Wards' comboBox

   ```
   Private Sub Wards_AfterUpdate()
   Dim txt As String
   txt = "SELECT Room FROM TblWards WHERE [Wards] = '" & Me.Wards.Value & "' ORDER BY Room;"
   Me.RoomN.RowSource = txt
   End Sub
   ```